# Which swift version for iOS 7+

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development, trying to develop an application.

Once I've seen in [these statistics](http://gs.statcounter.com/ios-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/worldwide) that iOS 7 has a really small market share I decided to support iOS 7 or higher in a way to make an app to all iphone OS available in the market. I also decided to use swift as code language but not sure which swift version should I choose.

Which swift version should I choose for iOS 7 or higher development?

Comment: Use the latest Swift version, there's no point in using older ones if you just start development. I'd also suggest targeting at least iOS9 (or rather iOS10 now that iOS12 is out) as targeting any older system gives you a really small number of extra possible users, while making it harder to maintain a clear codebase, since you'd have to check for iOS version when making use of newer system features.

Comment: AFAIK Appstore accepts only apps build with SDK one before current, so this defines swift version limitations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use the latest swift version `Swift 4.2`

As `iOS 12` is out now so you have to use `iOS 10 and above` because we should support recent 3 versions.

[image][image: iOS 12 statistics]

[Images source](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)

**If you target iOS 10 and above then you hit the 95% users**

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jogendar. Just for curiosity, does 'support recent previous 3 versions' is some kind of rule or just a good practice?

Comment: @JoséSilva: we can change according to client requirment but this is a good practice that we have to support recent 3 versions

Comment: Perfectly described @Jogendar, it makes a lot of sense. Thanks again for the help...

Comment: @JoséSilva: PLease tik green mark and upvote... Thanks in advance

Comment: I already tried to do that but couldn't once I do not have at least 15 reputation :/ By the way, can help me achieve that, giving an upvote to my question. As soon as I'm able, you can count with the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

[Apple states](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05072018a) that

> Starting July 2018, all iOS app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK and must support the Super Retina
>   display of iPhone X.

(The same requirement for new apps started on [April 2018](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02152018a).)

So, your choice are very few, Xcode 9 (with iOS 11 SDK) or Xcode 10 (with iOS 12 SDK).
(I believe we should read the requirement as *iOS11 SDK or later*.)

And supporting iOS 7 with Xcode 9/10 is very difficult. (I do not know if it is possible or not.) Deployment Target does not accept versions less than 8.0 (*), and iOS 7 Simulators are not provided.

(*) Some versions of Xcode replaces versions less than 7.0 to 8.0, even if I entered the version number manually. And at least, both Xcode versions does not show 7.x in the popup menu of the Deployment Target.

I recommend you to use the latest released version of Xcode (10, which comes with Swift 4.2), and make your minimum supported version to iOS 8.0 or later.

Comment: You *can* set the deployment target to 7.0 in Xcode 10, even if the pop-up does not offer that choice. I  don't know if that may cause problems.

Comment: @MartinR, seems Xcode 10 keeps the value 7.0. In Xcode 9 (or it might be some versions of older Xcodes) the value 7.0 was replaced to 8.0, when I opened other screens and back to the settings screen. Anyway, I will update the description about that.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift application will work only on iOS 7+. The Xcode will add the Swift library to every build so, you can use any version of Swift language and all of them will work on all iOS starting from 7th. Apps created with Swift will run on iOS 7+ and Mac OS 10.9 +

so use the latest version always.